# I want to draw a fractal, logically!

Tags: riddle, mathematics

> I want to draw a fractal, logically.
>
> It's not a fib, I assure you (well maybe...).
>
> If you have a plan,
>
> Then you're the man (or woman)!
>
> Please help me draw my fractal logically.

Hint 1 (a small one):

> There may be abbreviations, don't take the capitalization too literally, and things can have multiple meanings.

Hint 2 (small spoiler):

> I'm looking for an algorithm.

Hint 3 (big spoiler!!):

> It should use Boolean values.

Did I fib or not?

> Fib refers to the Fibonacci series, which can be used to draw a Sierpinski triangle, the fractal I want to draw.  The desired approach is somewhat different of course--it must be logical--but it's related.

Comment: Are you sure this is tagged correctly? It looks to me like this needs the [tag:riddle] tag (and possibly [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] as well).

Comment: No problem! The [tag:rhyme] tag may be applicable as well, as it looks like this is intended to be a limerick.

Comment: @F1Krazy It's not a limerick, and in fact doesn't even rhyme.

Comment: I think it means "Fib" and not "fib".  Proper nouns start with a capital letter.  This might be a snowflake or sponge of a question. :P

Comment: Well, it could be "fib" as in "minor lie". Though it wouldn't be astonishing if it were "Fib", short for Fibonacci...

Comment: I don't want to give anything away in the comments, but I've added some hints.  :)

Comment: I think my original wording may cause some confusion; added some more text to hopefully clear it up.  Bottom line though: once you get the main idea, don't overthink it.

Comment: I can give you a C-curve fractal algorithm that does not use Fibonacci series and that does use Boolean conditions...I do not see the relevance of your riddle though...

Comment: I added an update in spoiler blocks that clarifies where "fib" fits in as it has caused confusion.  It's at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a **really** neat way to draw a famous fractal, namely the

> [Sierpinski triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle)

using elementary logic only:

Step 1: take the numbers from $0$ to $2^n-1$ in two dimensions, use them as coordinates

Step 2: plot a 3D column graph, where the height of each bar is

> the bitwise NAND of the coordinate numbers at that point.

Here's what it looks like for n=4

> [image]
>  ([image source](http://www.pgrim.org/fractal/Solids.html))

Comment: that's cool...please tell me what it has to do with the original riddle?

Comment: @Drt Well, the riddle asks to draw a fractal logically, it is named after a man, fibonacci has nothing to do with it, and it fits the hints 2 and 3 extremely well. So... quite a lot, actually?

Comment: I think the line about "man or woman" in the riddle is a reference to (ROT13) "gur traqre **ovanel**".

Comment: Fibonacci comes into play; see the spoiler tag in the update for an explanation.

Comment: Awesome job bass!  I really like the graphic too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, while an image can follow later, consider this:

> Construct a right angled triangle with sides as 1,1. This gives a diagonal of size square root(2). Then form another right angled triangle, whose sides are the diagonal of the previous construction and 1, which results in a diagonal of size square root(3) and so on.

Then, joining

> the 'rotating' points of such a construction results in a spiral, leading later to a fractal.

Comment: That sounds interesting--I'd love to see the diagram.  You've got part of the idea but as a hint I'll point you back to the word "logically".